# Found some classes named like Class1$Class2, are those inner classes?

Tags: java

In class targte folder, found a lot of class1$class2, are those inner classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `class1$class2.class` is the class file of an inner class of the class `class1.class`.  This is the outputted class files you will see when you where your source looks something like:

```
public class class1 {
    class class2 {
    }
}
```